# What is the use of yield in Scala over map?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

In the below code **val_1** & **val_2** are returning the same values.

```
val lst = List("abc","def","ghi", "jkl")
val indexes = List(1,2,3)
val val_1 = for (index:Int <- indexes) yield lst(index)
val val_2 = indexes.map(index => lst(index))
```

**Output**

```
val_1: List[String] = List(def, ghi, jkl)
val_2: List[String] = List(def, ghi, jkl)
```

if **map** can do what we required, why do need **yield?**
Are there any other uses of **yield**?

Comment: A `for` comprehension, with `yield`, doesn't just act like `map`, it actually **is** a call to `map`. The compiler translates one to the other. So why have both? Because a `for` comprehension with multiple generators (the `<-` part) is usually much easier to read and understand than the `map`-`flatMap`-`withFilter` translation.

Answer (score 4):

using `for...yield` is just an alternative syntax for calling map.  We can see how the compiler desugars the for comprehension by compiling your code with the `-Xprint:parse` compiler flag.

```
  val lst = List("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl");
  val indexes = List(1, 2, 3);
  val val_1 = indexes.withFilter(((check$ifrefutable$1) => check$ifrefutable$1: @scala.unchecked match {
      case (index @ (_: Int)) => true
      case _ => false
    })).map(((index: Int) => lst(index)));
  val val_2 = indexes.map(((index) => lst(index)));
```

As you can see, the `for` code you used for val_1 just ends up being a call to `.map(((index: Int) => lst(index)))` same as the code for val_2.

The withFilter part is due to `index:Int <- indexes` causing a pattern match, since you declare here that index must be an Int.  If we remove the type annotation so the line is just `val val_1 = for (index <- indexes) yield lst(index)` and recompile, you will get the below output.

```
  val lst = List("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl");
  val indexes = List(1, 2, 3);
  val val_1 = indexes.map(((index) => lst(index)));
  val val_2 = indexes.map(((index) => lst(index)));
```

Now it is obvious that both the `for` and the explicit `map` are identical once compiled.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (index:Int <- indexes) yield lst(index)
```

This is a [for comprehension](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html). This particular example is the simplest form of using this. And it is equivalent to `List.map`.

According to [FAQ/yield](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html)

> Scala’s “for comprehensions” are equivalent to Haskell’s “do” notation, and it is nothing more than a syntactic sugar for composition of multiple monadic operations.

Is it different?

> Scala’s “for comprehensions” are syntactic sugar for composition of multiple operations with `foreach`, `map`, `flatMap`, `filter` or `withFilter`

Why?

> When you look at very simple for comprehensions, the map/foreach alternatives look, indeed, better. Once you start composing them, though, you can easily get lost in parenthesis and nesting levels. When that happens, for comprehensions are usually much clearer.